# Animation twitches/jumps between Keyframes

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, rigify

I'm currently working on my first 3D animation and stumbled upon this:
Blender animates the movement between my keys, but here and there there is weird twitching between them.

[image: (gif of walking animation)]

It's like there are invisible keys that the body parts just jump to instead of smoothly animating.

My F-Curves are set to Bezier (even though I tried Linear without any changes) and I used the middle mouse button to go down in the timeline to see if there were any keys I missed.
I used the blender rigify addon for the armature.

Blender 2.91

The Project:
[image]

Comment: Share your file.  Remove the model first if you prefer. I only need to see the rig. https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: yes please share the file. Keeping the model with it is better too.

Comment: Thx, I edited my post

Comment: Are you trying to create a walk in place? Or a walk through space?

Comment: For now in just place to figure things out.

Comment: Okay. I can't find the pole vectors for your leg IKs. I thought I found them at one point, but I was wrong. Without seeing those, I can't figure out if you might have unwanted keyframes on them that are causing the knees to jump.

Comment: Note: If you're trying to create a walk in place, you will want the bones that have already been keyframed to have the same positions on the ending keyframe of the cycle as they had on the starting frame of the cycle. Right now, your model ends up farther forward at the end than at the beginning. That causes a lurch backward when the cycle repeats. Copying and pasting keyframes from the beginning of the cycle to the end can fix this. Though it doesn't fix the motion completely in this case because there are still other issues.

Comment: @R-800 Note noted :). As stated before it's not how the end product should look like, but thx for the reminder.
As for the pole vectors: Idk where or what they are, sry, noob at work

Comment: If you activate foot_ik bone "Toggle Pole" button will be shown in the side bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you activate foot_ik bone "Toggle Pole" button will be shown in the
> side bar. - tetii

That was it! After toggling I saw that there was something seriously wrong with my legs. I deleted the key-frames and redid them, now everything works fine.
Thanks.

[image: Toggle Pole Button]